# How can I make std:::cin take input up to the first non-integar and then discard the rest?

Tags: c++, user-input, iostream, cin

The

way this code currently functions is that if a non-number is input it will set the error flag, clear the error then ignore.

However if A user inputs a number followed by a non number such as 2garbage1 it will succeed and pass 5 into the first variable \n into the next variable and garbage1 into the third variable.

```
>
```

```
do {
    std::cout << "\n\nPlease Enter the number of Names you would like to store: ";
    std::cin >> noOfNames;  // get user input for the number of names the user would like to enter.



    if (!(valid_input = std::cin.good())) { // if valid input does not = true 
        std::cout << "That input is invalid!\n";
        std::cin.clear(); //Clear stream to remove error flag
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore everything and deliminate with \n     


    }
} while (!valid_input);

for (int i = 0; i < noOfNames; i++) //forloop which will iterate through the number of names getting user input on each iteration
{
    std::cout << "Enter name #" << i + 1 << ": "; // the i + 1 will avoid displaying name #1 as name #0 since i begins at 0
    std::cin >> tempName; // get user input and store it in tempName
    vec2.push_back(tempName); // add tempName to vec2
}
```

If 2garbage1 was input it would output this:

> "Please enter the number of names you would like to store: 2garbage1
>
> Name #1 =
> Name #2 = garbage1

obviously that's not ideal and I'd like to discard anything after the final number.

Links and resources so I can read up/watch videos about the topic too would be appreciated I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for on google and even if I do I'd like to understand what the code is doing.

Comment: It's actually not complex. Read the input as a string, analyse the string to see if it matches your expectations of a number, if so then convert the string to a number, otherwise signal an error. I guess your mistake is assuming that they would be some 'quick' way of doing this, but there isn't. If you have particular input requirements, then you are going to have to write the code.

Comment: Keep in mind that `std::cin`, like all streams, traffics in **text**, not numbers. There are convenience functions for converting that text to numbers, but if they're not convenient for what you need, don't use them.